# How can I check to see if a string contains characters of whitespace/alphanumeric/etc?

Tags: ios, swift, ctype

How can you use the "ctype.h" library in Swift to be able to use `isAlpha` or `isSpace` on characters? Or is there a better, Swift, way of doing it?

This question is answered, but it doesn't seem to work:
[Swift: how to find out if letter is Alphanumeric or Digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502669/swift-how-to-find-out-if-letter-is-alphanumeric-or-digit)

It doesn't specify how to import the library. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
extension String {
    subscript (i : Int) -> String {
        return String(Array(self)[i])
    }
}

let whitespace = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()

let phrase = "Test case"

for var i=0; i<countElements(phrase); i++ {
    if whitespace.characterIsMember(phrase[i]) { //error
        println("char is whitespace")
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it a good idea to use methods that don't support Unicode on Swift strings?

Comment: It seems that the (ASCII-only) functions isAlpha(), isDigit() have been removed from Swift. But the NSCharacterSet-based method from that answer should still work.

Comment: I'm trying to use that (NSCharacterSet), but it keeps saying "character is not convertible to unichar".

Comment: Post your code. Remember how Swift handles automatic conversions between different primitive types?

Comment: Updated the question with the code I have.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use NSCharacter on the entire string,not character-by-character:

```
let whitespace = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()

let phrase = "Test case"
let range = phrase.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(whitespace)

// range will be nil if no whitespace is found
if let test = range {
    println("whitespace found")
}
else {
    println("whitespace not found")
}
```

Output:

```
whitespace found
```

Answer (score 11):

I created a String extension that does exactly this, hope it's useful.

```
extension String {
    func containsWhitespaceAndNewlines() -> Bool {
        return rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespacesAndNewlines) != nil
    }
}

// Usage
"hello, world!".containsWhitespaceAndNewlines() // true
"hello,world!".containsWhitespaceAndNewlines() // false
```

Answer (score 10):

Shorter extension (swift 4.1)

```
extension String {
    var containsWhitespace : Bool {
        return(self.rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespacesAndNewlines) != nil)
    }
}
```

You can change the `.whitespacesAndNewlines` with any other `CharacterSet` like this:

```
extension String {
    var containsDigits : Bool {
        return(self.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits) != nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer works with text fields. I was going crazy trying to search for whitespace on a UItextfield without searching the string content of it. This works for UItextfields:

**Swift 4:**

```
    if (textField.text?.contains(" "))!{
        print("Has space")
    }else{
        print("Does not have space")
    }
```

This is for a regular string, also in swift 4

```
    if string.contains(" "){
        print("Has space")
    }else{
        print("Does not have space")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 5

```
extension String {

    func containsWhiteSpace() -> Bool {

        // check if there's a range for a whitespace
        let range = self.rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

        // returns false when there's no range for whitespace
        if let _ = range {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just use regex:

```
extension String {
   func isContainWhiteSpace() -> Bool {
       let whiteSpace = "\\s+"
       let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", whiteSpace)
       return predicate.evaluate(with: self)
   }
}
```

**Meaning:**

"\s" mean Any white space character 
"+" mean One or More of character 
Notice the double **back slash** we can't use single **back slash** as it'll return error: **Invalid escape sequence in literal** so we need to use double **back slash** to avoid that error.

**Usage:**

```
let sample = " "
print(sample.isContainWhiteSpace() ? "Contain White Space" : "Acceptable White Space")
```

**Note:** I use this in case I want to validate when user try to input empty white space, this will prevent user to do so.

Answer (score -1):

This function will tell you if there is a whitespace between a string. for example if you are trying to make sure the user enter a first and last name

**Swift 5**

```
func validatTextField() -> Bool {
        var isValid = false
        if textField.text!.contains(" ") && !textField.text!.isEmpty{
            let cardHolderChar = textField.text!
            for i in cardHolderChar {
                if i == " " && i == cardHolderChar.last {
                    isValid = false
                }
                else {
                    isValid = true
                }
            }
        }
        return isValid
    }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? You haven't provided any comment