# How to eliminate an input when there is a space in a String in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

I am having trouble right now. I set a custom `TextField`. When users type any word in the box, I want the data to be saved, but I want to set a condition which is every time a word is entered, only one word is allowed in a `String` text. For example, if a user enters a text which is like "Hello", es, I want it to be saved because as it fulfills the condition. However, if it is "hello, world", "hello ", " hello", "I am a super man" or anything like a text with some space in a `String` text, it is not allowed.

```
for space in text {
     if space == " " {
         print("Enter only one word please")
         return
     }
}
```

This is my attempt to solve this, but it is not working well. I wonder if I should use an array to achive my goal but I have no idea. User inputs should be allowed if there is no space.

Thank you.

Comment: You should use swift String class `contains(otherString: Sting)` method. like `text.contains(" ")`. It will return true if string contains space

Comment: @Aks Hey, awesome! You solved my isssu!!! It was so simple aproach to do this! Thanks man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function to check if there are any spaces in your string:

```
func validate(string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.whitespaces) == nil
}
```

Or this one to check if input contains only letters:

```
func validate(string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters.inverted) == nil
}
```

An example of how to actually use it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //...
    func textField(textField: UITextField!, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String!) -> Bool {
        let currentString: NSString = (textField.text ?? "") as NSString
        let newString = currentString.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        return  validate(string: newString)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to check for spaces, your code is almost correct. You only need to change this:

```
for space in text {
```

to this:

```
for space in text.characters {
```

If you want to check for all whitespaces, try this:

```
for c in text.characters {
    let string = String(c)
    let unicodeScalar = s.unicodeScalars.first!
    if CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines.contains(unicodeScalar) {
        // contains whitespace
    }
}
```

Comment: You can avoid looping through the characters by using `rangeOfCharacter` method. It is shorter and more readable as for me.

Comment: This approach is interesting to me! Is there any difference between just writing text.contains(" ")?

Comment: @ryohei that only checks for spaces. If you want to check for all white spaces you can't use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your issue.

```
let phrase = “Your text here“

let whitespace = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceCharacterSet()
let range = phrase.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(whitespace)

// range will be nil if no whitespace is found
if let test = range {
    print("Enter only one word please")
         return
}
```

Inspired from the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883924/how-can-i-check-to-see-if-a-string-contains-characters-of-whitespace-alphanumeri)

Answer (score -1):

Use regular expression to solve this validation.

```
let stringInput = "epninijjk werewr"

let regEx = "(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,30}$)"

do {
let reularExpression = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regEx, options: .CaseInsensitive)
let reuslt = reularExpression.matchesInString(stringInput, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: email.characters.count))
if reuslt.isEmpty{
    print("Not valid")
}
else{
    print("Valid")
} 
}
catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

Here {2,30} 2 is the minimum number of characters and 30 is the maximum limit.

You can change according to your requirement.

Add special characters in [a-zA-Z0-9] , if you want to allow.

Comment: I found @Aks answer was fairly simple and easy to solve my issue. This looks so complicated for now i guess, but thanks for helping me figure out this issue!