# What is the replacement for isDigit() for characters in Swift?

Tags: swift

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502669/swift-how-to-find-out-if-letter-is-alphanumeric-or-digit), before Xcode 6 Beta 4, one could use `c.isDigit()` and `c.isAlpha()` to find if `c : Character` was a digit or alpha. The post mentions that this was removed as it was only effective for ASCII characters.

My question is, what's the replacement? Short of setting up a function with a switch statement for alphanumeric options, how can I test a character on its digit-ness?

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked contains an example that continues to work.

Comment: My problem is that I only have the one character. Suppose I have `var c : Character` and I want to see if it complies with /[0-9]/. According to that answer, I should do `NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().longCharacterIsMember(c)`, but it tells me "'Character is not convertible to 'UTF32Char'", so I try `NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().longCharacterIsMember(UTF32Char(c))` and get that I "Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument of type 'UTF32Char'"

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The "problem" is that a Swift character does not directly correspond to a Unicode
code point, but represents an "extended grapheme cluster" which can consist of 
multiple Unicode scalars. For example

```
let c : Character = "" // REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTERS US
```

is actually a sequence of *two* Unicode scalars.

If we ignore this fact then you can retrieve the *initial* Unicode scalar of the
character (compare [How can I get the Unicode code point(s) of a Character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102044/how-can-i-get-the-unicode-code-points-of-a-character)) and test its membership in a character set:

```
let c : Character = "5"

let s = String(c).unicodeScalars
let uni = s[s.startIndex]

let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
let isADigit = digits.longCharacterIsMember(uni.value)
```

This returns "true" for the characters "0" ... "9", but actually for *all*
Unicode scalars of the ["decimal digit category"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm), for example:

```
let c1 : Character = "৯" // BENGALI DIGIT NINE U+09EF
let c2 : Character = "" // MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK DIGIT ONE U+1D7D9
```

If you care only for the (ASCII) digits "0" ... "9", then the easiest method is probably:

```
if c >= "0" && c <= "9" { }
```

or, using ranges:

```
if "0"..."9" ~= c { }
```

---

**Update:** As of Swift 5 you can check for ASCII digits with

```
if c.isASCII && c.isNumber { }
```

using the “Character properties“ introduced with [SE-0221](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0221-character-properties.md).

This solves also the problem with digits modified by a variation selected U+FE0F, like the Keycap Emoji "1️⃣". (Thanks to Lukas Kukacka for reporting this problem.)

```
let c: Character = "1️⃣"
print(Array(c.unicodeScalars)) // ["1", "\u{FE0F}", "\u{20E3}"]
print(c.isASCII && c.isNumber) // false
```

Comment: The "only ASCII" check does not seem to be 100% reliable. It will fail for characters like "1️⃣" (keycap emoji: https://emojipedia.org/keycap-digit-one/). For example `("0"..."9").contains(Character("1️⃣"))` returns `true`, which is unexpected for simple ASCII 0-9 check..

Comment: @LukasKukacka: You are right. I *think* that the way how strings (or characters) are compared changed in Swift 4 (or 5). The easiest way to check for ASCII digits in Swift 5 would be  `if c.isASCII && c.isNumber`. I'll check it later and update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 21):

With Swift 5, according to your needs, you may choose one of the following ways in order to solve you problem.

---

### #1. Using `Character`'s [`isNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127015-isnumber) property

Character has a property called `isNumber`. `isNumber` has the following declaration:

```
var isNumber: Bool { get }
```

> A Boolean value indicating whether this character represents a number.

The Playground sample codes below show how to check if a character represents a number using `isNumber`:

```
let character: Character = "9"
print(character.isNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "½"
print(character.isNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "④"
print(character.isNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "1⃣"
print(character.isNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "1️⃣"
print(character.isNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "৯"
print(character.isNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = ""
print(character.isNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "F"
print(character.isNumber) // false
```

---

### #2. Using `Character`'s [`isWholeNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127020-iswholenumber) property

If you want to check if a character represents a whole number, you can use `Character`'s `isWholeNumber` property:

```
let character: Character = "9"
print(character.isWholeNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "½"
print(character.isWholeNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "④"
print(character.isWholeNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "1⃣"
print(character.isWholeNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "1️⃣"
print(character.isWholeNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "৯"
print(character.isWholeNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = ""
print(character.isWholeNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "F"
print(character.isWholeNumber) // false
```

---

### #3. Using `Unicode.Scalar.Properties`'s [`generalCategory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081566-generalcategory) property and `Unicode.GeneralCategory.decimalNumber`

The Playground sample codes below show how to check if the first Unicode scalar of a character is a decimal number using `generalCategory` and `Unicode.GeneralCategory.decimalNumber`:

```
let character: Character = "9"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first! // DIGIT NINE
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .decimalNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "½"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first! // VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .decimalNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "④"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first! // CIRCLED DIGIT FOUR
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .decimalNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "1⃣"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first! // DIGIT ONE
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .decimalNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "1️⃣"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first! // DIGIT ONE
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .decimalNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "৯"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first! // BENGALI DIGIT NINE
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .decimalNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = ""
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first! // MATHEMATICAL DOUBLE-STRUCK DIGIT ONE
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .decimalNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "F"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first! // LATIN CAPITAL LETTER F
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .decimalNumber) // false
```

---

### #4. Using `Unicode.Scalar.Properties`'s [`generalCategory`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081566-generalcategory) property and `Unicode.GeneralCategory.otherNumber`

Similarly, you can check that the first Unicode scalar of a character corresponds to the category *Other_Number* in the Unicode Standard using `generalCategory` and `Unicode.GeneralCategory.otherNumber`:

```
let character: Character = "9"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .otherNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "½"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .otherNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "④"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .otherNumber) // true
```

```
let character: Character = "1⃣"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .otherNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "1️⃣"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .otherNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "৯"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .otherNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = ""
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .otherNumber) // false
```

```
let character: Character = "F"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.generalCategory == .otherNumber) // false
```

---

### #5. Using `CharacterSet`'s [`decimalDigits`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/characterset/1779641-decimaldigits) property

As an alternative, you can import Foundation and check if `CharacterSet.decimalDigits` contains the first Unicode scalar of a character:

```
import Foundation

let character: Character = "9"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(scalar)) // true
```

```
import Foundation

let character: Character = "½"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(scalar)) // false
```

```
import Foundation

let character: Character = "④"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(scalar)) // false
```

```
import Foundation

let character: Character = "1⃣"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(scalar)) // true
```

```
import Foundation

let character: Character = "1️⃣"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(scalar)) // true
```

```
import Foundation

let character: Character = "৯"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(scalar)) // true
```

```
import Foundation

let character: Character = ""
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(scalar)) // true
```

```
import Foundation

let character: Character = "F"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(scalar)) // false
```

---

## #6. Using `Unicode.Scalar.Properties`'s [`numericType`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unicode/scalar/properties/3081613-numerictype)

Apple documentation states for `numericType`:

> For scalars that represent a number, numericType is the numeric type of the scalar. For all other scalars, this property is `nil`.

The sample codes below show the possible numeric type (`decimal`, `digit` or `numeric`) for the first scalar of a given character:

```
let character: Character = "9"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.numericType) // Optional(Swift.Unicode.NumericType.decimal)
```

```
let character: Character = "½"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.numericType) // Optional(Swift.Unicode.NumericType.numeric)
```

```
let character: Character = "④"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.numericType) // Optional(Swift.Unicode.NumericType.digit)
```

```
let character: Character = "1⃣"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.numericType) // Optional(Swift.Unicode.NumericType.decimal)
```

```
let character: Character = "1️⃣"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.numericType) // Optional(Swift.Unicode.NumericType.decimal)
```

```
let character: Character = "৯"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.numericType) // Optional(Swift.Unicode.NumericType.decimal)
```

```
let character: Character = ""
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.numericType) // Optional(Swift.Unicode.NumericType.decimal)
```

```
let character: Character = "F"
let scalar = character.unicodeScalars.first!
print(scalar.properties.numericType) // nil
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 seems a little easier:

```
let str = "abcdef12345"
let digitSet = CharacterSet.decimalDigits

for ch in str.unicodeScalars {
    if digitSet.contains(ch) {
        // is digit!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### About **Swift 3**:

According to the great Martin R answer's , for who have problems with the new swift:

replace:

```
let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet()
```

with:

```
let digits = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits as NSCharacterSet
```

Answer (score 4):

For a single character:

```
CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(string.unicodeScalars.first!)
```

Comment: Quite handy and fast if you want to know that string has a digit or not

Answer (score 0):

I have create mine var to check whether character is number or not.

```
var isNumber : Bool {
    get{
        return !self.isEmpty && self.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted) == nil
    }
}
```

// Use

```
var initial = "1"
if let isNum = initial.isNumber, isNum { // true
    initial = "#"
}
```