# The array value should be sort like (alphabetic, numbers and special characters)

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to sort like the array as follows:

```
let students: Set = ["23412334","&234@fwv","Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku", "Akosua"]
let sortedStudents = students.sorted()
print(sortedStudents)
```

Output:

```
["&234@fwv", "23412334", "Abena", "Akosua", "Kofi", "Kweku", "Peter"]
```

But I need like

```
["Abena", "Akosua", "Kofi", "Kweku", "Peter", "23412334","&234@fwv"]
```

Comment: In the natural convention of sorting, I don't think that's possible. You need to write your own function as an extension for arrays and then use it.

Comment: Use a closure in which you defined your own logic for the sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
let words = ["23412334","&234@fwv","Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku", "Akosua"]

func sortedNumbersLast(words: [String]) -> [String] {
    var startsWithDigit     = [String]()
    var startsWithCharacter = [String]()
    var startsWithSymbol    = [String]()


    for word in words {
        if let first = word.characters.first {
            if first >= "0" && first <= "9" {
                startsWithDigit.append(word)
            }
            else {
                if(!(first >= "a" && first <= "z") && !(first >= "A" && first <= "Z") ){
                    startsWithSymbol.append(word)
                }else{
                    startsWithCharacter.append(word)
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return startsWithCharacter.sorted(by: <) + startsWithDigit.sorted(by: <) + startsWithSymbol.sorted()
}
print(sortedNumbersLast(words: words))
```

`["Abena", "Akosua", "Kofi", "Kweku", "Peter", "23412334", "&234@fwv"]`

[Modified Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33509650/2475420)

Comment: Sorry friend..... can you pls tell me....if I use dictionary array, how to do it like {
            PhoneNumbers = 5554787672;
            fullName = "Daniel Higgins";
        }

Answer (score 3):

The "correct" way to do it is to define your own sort comparator and use `sorted(by:)` which sorts using your comparator. In the example below, I define a "priority" based on the category of the first character in the string, and then a two level sort based first on priority and then on the normal string ordering

```
extension String
{
    enum Priority
    {
        case normal
        case low
        case lowest
        static let lowPriority: Set<Character> = Set(["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"])
        static let lowestPriority: Set<Character> = Set(["&"])

        static func < (a: Priority, b: Priority) -> Bool
        {
            switch (a, b)
            {
            case (.normal, .low), (.normal, .lowest), (.low, .lowest):
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        }
    }

    var priority: Priority
    {
        let first = self.characters.first! // fatal error for empty strings
        if Priority.lowestPriority.contains(first)
        {
            return .lowest
        }
        else if Priority.lowPriority.contains(first)
        {
            return .low
        }
        return .normal
    }
}

let students: Set = ["23412334","&234@fwv","Kofi", "Abena", "Peter", "Kweku", "Akosua"]

let sortedStudents = students.sorted {
    (a, b) -> Bool in
    if a.priority < b.priority
    {
        return true
    }
    else if b.priority < a.priority
    {
        return false
    }
    return a < b
}
print(sortedStudents)
```

There may be bugs still, but it works for your test case.

Comment: Friend..... please help me.... can you pls tell me....if I use dictionary array, how to do it like { PhoneNumbers = 5554787672; fullName = "Daniel Higgins"; }

Comment: @joelprithivi It's probably best to ask that as another question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

- First sort the array as you have sorted.
- Remove the strings starting with special characters and save it in another array.
- Remove the strings starting with numerics and save it in another array.
- Append the numeric array to original array.
- Append the special character array to original array.