# How to sort tableview cells in this use case

Tags: swift, sorting, tableview

**What is the best practice of sorting this table in Swift 4?** 
*A-Z*

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        list = [ ghost(name:"alphabet".localized, id:"1"),
             ghost(name:"élephant".localized, id:"2"),
             ghost(name:"delegate".localized, id:"3")]
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1 
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if filtering() { 
            return filter.count 
        }
        return list.count 
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "library", for: indexPath)
        var data: ghost

        if filtering() { 
            data = filter[indexPath.row] 
        }
        else { 
            data = list[indexPath.row] 
        }

        cell.textLabel!.text = data.name
        return cell 
    }
```

I am using translated strings a lot. So it would be nice, if the table can be loaded alphabetically in different language. Can someone help me with that? I searched the whole internet and just got too exhausted of this... Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand. When you set `filter` or `list`, just sort it.

Comment: @Larme the question is how exactly. can you make this comment an actual answer, please? ^^

Comment: `filterOrFilter = someArrayOfGhosts.sort{ $0.name < $1.name}` ?

Comment: the code formatting alone deserves a down vote

Comment: @vikingosegundo code formating is fixed :)

Comment: maybe you can upvote then :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it as follows:

```
func sortAlpha() {

    if filtering() {
        filter.sort { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
            return item1.name > item2.name
        }
    }
    else {
        list.sort { (item1, item2) -> Bool in
            return item1.name > item2.name
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

then just call `sortAlpha()`

Comment: then just call sortAlpha() when you got the list, before reload data. Where are you trying to sort it anyway?

Comment: "alphabet".localized should return string at the end - in viewDidLoad what happens if you call sortAlpha?

Comment: you are awesome :) it's working. but now I've got Z-A and I am using some characters like á é and so on, these are on top of the table; then Z ..... A

Comment: You can try things like ascii encoding string and then sort or look for another solution for special characters sort

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277831/the-array-value-should-be-sort-like-alphabetic-numbers-and-special-characters should work. if you use some other function for  sorting you can create it as bool and return its result instead of item1.name > item2.name. e.g. return mySortFunc()

Comment: oh c'mon I was just editing code formatting while the website told me you had more recent edit on it -.- I don't like downvotes :D