# How to sort a String array based on letter/symbol/number

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have a `String` array

`let myArray = ["b", "a", "*", "c", "5"]`

I want tot sort it. After the sort, sorted letters should be first and symbols and number should follow.

```
let sortedArray = myArray.sorted { $0 < $1 }
print(sortedArray) 
//I get ["*", "5", "a", "b", "c"]
//I want ["a", "b", "c", "5", "*"]
```

EDIT: I saw this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510593/11922257). Is there any short/better way?

Comment: I don‘t think so

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way, I wrote this function, much shorter than the one you linked. Hope you enjoy it! :)

```
func sortCharacters(array : [String]) -> [String] {
    let letters = array.joined().filter {$0.isLetter}.sorted()
    let numbers = array.joined().filter {$0.isNumber}.sorted()
    let symbols = array.joined().filter {!$0.isLetter && !$0.isNumber}.sorted()
    return Array(letters + numbers + symbols).map {String($0)}
}

let chars = ["*", "5", "a", "b", "c"]
print(sortCharacters(array: chars)) //["a", "b", "c", "5", "*"]
```