# Checking if first 3 characters of UI TextField are numeric in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I want to check if the first three characters entered in the UI Textfield are numbers. I could do this easily in Python, but for some reason in Swift it's a pain.

Here's my python if statements (which I want to 'translate' into swift as it works):

```
str = "123abc"                                                                  
if str.isdigit():                               
        if str[:3]:                         
            print(str)
```

and here's my swift code

```
@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!

@IBAction func checkBarcodeRegion(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        let text: String = input.text!

        if text.prefix(3)
        {
           //if numeric
               //do something
        }
    }
```

Can't get this to work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the replacement for isDigit() for characters in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351625/what-is-the-replacement-for-isdigit-for-characters-in-swift)

Answer (score 3):

Three alternatives:

Create an `Int` from the substring and check if for non-nil.

```
let isNumeric1 = Int(text.prefix(3)) != nil
```

Remove all digits from the substring with Regular Expression and check for empty string

```
let isNumeric2 = text.prefix(3).replacingOccurrences(of: "[0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression).isEmpty
```

Split the substring by the `decimalDigits` character set and check if the number of components is 4

```
let isNumeric3 = text.prefix(3).components(separatedBy: .decimalDigits).count == 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `prefix` is the right direction to go. You can use `allSatisfy` after that to check if they are all digits. One of the ways to check for digits is to check if the unicode scalar is in the `CharacterSet.decimalDigits` set.

```
text.unicodeScalars.prefix(3)
    .allSatisfy(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains)
```

This will check for all the digits in Unicode, including the ones that the Indians and Arabic use.

If by digits you mean the ASCII 0123456789, then you could use:

```
text.prefix(3).allSatisfy(("0"..."9").contains)
```

Comment: No need to use a closure `text.unicodeScalars.prefix(3)
    .allSatisfy(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains)` and `text.prefix(3).allSatisfy( ("0"..."9").contains)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I guess that's a bit shorter. Edited.