# How can I check if a string contains letters in Swift?

Tags: swift, nscharacterset

I'm trying to check whether a specific string contains letters or not.

So far I've come across `NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()` as a set of letters, but I'm having trouble checking whether a character in that set is in the given string. When I use this code, I get an error stating:

> 'Character' is not convertible to 'unichar'

For the following code:

```
for chr in input{
    if letterSet.characterIsMember(chr){
        return "Woah, chill out!"
    }
}
```

Comment: Compare [What is the best way to determine if a string contains a character from a set in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486138/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-if-a-string-contains-a-character-from-a-set-in) ?

Comment: @MartinR Why "compare"? It looks like a pretty solid duplicate to me.

Comment: **Swift 5+** This is definitely not (or no longer) a duplicate.... The linked question asks to check against a predefined list of characters. This asks if the string contains letters. This can now be done with a one liner and built-in Swift method: `yourString.allSatisfy { $0.isLetter }`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use `NSCharacterSet` in the following way :

```
let letters = NSCharacterSet.letters

let phrase = "Test case"
let range = phrase.rangeOfCharacter(from: letters)

// range will be nil if no letters is found
if let test = range {
    println("letters found")
}
else {
   println("letters not found")
}
```

Or you can do this too :

```
func containsOnlyLetters(input: String) -> Bool {
   for chr in input {
      if (!(chr >= "a" && chr <= "z") && !(chr >= "A" && chr <= "Z") ) {
         return false
      }
   }
   return true
}
```

> In Swift 2:

```
func containsOnlyLetters(input: String) -> Bool {
   for chr in input.characters {
      if (!(chr >= "a" && chr <= "z") && !(chr >= "A" && chr <= "Z") ) {
         return false
      }
   }
   return true
}
```

It's up to you, choose a way. I hope this help you.

Comment: Your second code block does not compile in Swift, you have to use double-quotes.

Comment: I tried the first solution, and it worked, though I'm not sure I understand the  `if let test = range` line.

Comment: @user199470 the `if let test = range` it's the way to test if `range` isn't `nil` , nothing else, in which case it's only letters what it contains.

Comment: the first solution is elegant.

Comment: It should be made clear that while the first example, using `NSCharacterSet`, works with non-English letters as well (German, Spanish, even Hebrew, and hopefully Arabic, too), the second only works with english letters, which may not be what international users would expect.

Comment: Swift 4: `if let _ = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: NSCharacterSet.letters) { }`

Answer (score 8):

You should use the `String`s built in range functions with `NSCharacterSet` rather than roll your own solution. This will give you a lot more flexibility too (like case insensitive search if you so desire).

```
let str = "Hey this is a string"
let characterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "aeiou")

if let _ = str.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(characterSet, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) {
    println("true")
}
else {
    println("false")
}
```

Substitute `"aeiou"` with whatever letters you're looking for.

A less flexible, but fun swift note all the same, is that you can use any of the functions available for `Sequence`s. So you can do this:

```
contains("abc", "c")
```

This of course will only work for individual characters, and is not flexible and not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

The trouble with `.characterIsMember` is that it takes a `unichar` (a typealias for `UInt16`).

If you iterate your input using the `utf16` view of the string, it will work:

```
let set = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet()
for chr in input.utf16 {
    if set.characterIsMember(chr) {
        println("\(chr) is a letter")
    }
}
```

You can also skip the loop and use the `contains` algorithm if you only want to check for presence/non-presence:

```
if contains(input.utf16, { set.characterIsMember($0) }) {
    println("contains letters")
}
```

Comment: NSCharacterSet has also a method longCharacterIsMember, which can be used with the "full" Unicode values, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24502779/1187415 for an example.

Comment: Ah thanks, that’s better but there’s still edge cases (“!͖̬̰̙̗̿̋ͥͥ̂ͣ̐́́͜͞” will be flagged as letters)

Comment: Interestingly not by a regex with `[:alpha:]` though

Comment: Interesting, how did you find that beast?