# Is there a function that checks if a character in a string is a letter in the alphabet? (Swift)

Tags: python, swift

I'm converting a python programme into swift, and one section uses a for loop to keep every character within a string if it is a letter. In python, it's as simple as using '.isalpha()', is there anything in swift that does this? Code in python:

```
word = 'hello 123'
new_word = []
for i in word:
    if i.isalpha():
        new_word.append(i)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502669/swift-how-to-find-out-if-letter-is-alphanumeric-or-digit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Xcode 8 beta4 • Swift 3**

```
extension String {
    var lettersOnly: String {
        return components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.letters.inverted).joined(separator:"")
    }
    var lettersArray: [Character] {
        return Array(lettersOnly.characters)
    }
}
```

**Xcode 7.3.1 • Swift 2.2.1**

```
extension String {
    var lettersOnly: String {
        return componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet().invertedSet).joinWithSeparator("")
    }
    var lettersArray: [Character] {
        return Array(lettersOnly.characters)
    }
}
```

---

**Swift 1.x**

```
import UIKit

extension String {

    var lettersOnly: String {
        return "".join(componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet().invertedSet))
    }
    var lettersArray: [Character] {
        return Array("".join(componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet().invertedSet)))
    }


}
let word = "hello 123"

let letters = word.lettersOnly        // "hello"

let lettersArray = word.lettersArray  // ["h", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

Comment: Hi, i tried this out, and i got this error: "use of unresolved identifier 'NSCharacterSet' ". Not exactly the desired result.

Comment: you need to add  import UIKit or import Foundation

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/letterCharacterSet

Comment: I'll try it out again later

Comment: Do you want an array of characters as result ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just:

```
let alphabet: [Character] = [
  "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m",
  "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"
]

let word = "h4e7l2l8o1"

var answer = [String]()

for letter in word {
  if contains(alphabet, letter) {
    answer.append(String(letter))
  }
}

"".join(answer) // "hello"
```

or even:

```
let answer = "".join(filter(word) {contains(alphabet, $0)}.map{String($0)}) // "hello"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import Foundation // For playground or REPL

let word = "This is a string !#€%!€#% 123456 åäö é 中國"
let letterCharSet = NSCharacterSet.letterCharacterSet().invertedSet
let newWord = "".join(word.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(letterCharSet))
// Outputs: "Thisisastringåäöé中國"
```

Comment: so does this work with any letter from any language?

Comment: Yes, might be a feature or a problem. Depending of what your looking for. :)

Comment: This is exactly the same thing I answered. All you did was to dismantle it.

Comment: @Leonardo: Sorry did not see your answer. Had the answer window open for some time... And yes, my answer is the same as yours, and you where first and should be accepted, if the suggested approach works.