# Extract numbers from a String and save them to an array

Tags: swift, characterview

Hello my Friends i need ur help! :) Im an absolute beginner in swift and have absolutely no idea what i'm doing.

I need to extract all numbers from a txt file which i converted into a string.
I want to save all the numbers into a new Array and i also have to use CharacterView to solve the problem.

This is what i got so far. Reading from the txt file is no problem.

```
func readFile(){
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "paragraph", ofType: "txt")

    var fileContents : String? = nil
    do {
        fileContents = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } catch _ as NSError {
        //ERROR HANDLING
    }
     print(fileContents)

}
```

this is the file:

> § 9 Lorem ipsum dolor (1) sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed
>   diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam.
>   (2) Bed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo 55 dolores
>   et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren. (3) 1 abore et dolore magna
>   aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
>   dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: What is the structure of your file? How do you plan on storing the numbers?

Comment: Include a sample of the content in your `paragraph9.txt` file

Comment: Thx for you answers. i added the txt file below the question

Comment: Show what output you are hoping to get. Do you just want `[1,2,3]`???? Or `[9,1,2,55,3,1]`??? What?

Comment: yeah exactly [9,1,2,55,3,1]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24502779/4962554) solves the core of your problem. Try it out.

Comment: _i also have to use CharacterView to solve the problem_ Is this just an example you think of to solve your issue? Or some sort of requirement given as a homework?

Comment: Hmm, seems it's not a requirement reading comments to answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy way to do it, unfortunately it does not use `CharacterView` because that would complicate it greatly:

```
func readFile(){
  // Make sure getting the path and reading the file succeeds
  guard
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "paragraph", ofType: "txt"),
    let fileContents = try? String(contentsOfFile: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) 
    else { return }

  // split string into substrings that only contain numbers
  let substrings = fileContents.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)

  // flatMap performs action on each substring
  // and only returns non-nil values,
  // thus returns [Int]

  let numbers = substrings.flatMap {
    // convert each substring into an Int?
    return Int($0)
  }

  print(numbers)
}
```

Because the initializer for `Int` takes a `String` there is no need to use `CharacterView`. Once the numbers in the text are split from their non-digits they can be converted directly from `String` to `Int`. To use `CharacterView` would be an unnecessary intermediate. You could, however, code your own version of `Int` `init?(String)` which uses `CharacterView` to build the value.

Comment: Note that I didn't need the variable `substrings`, I could have skipped it and done `fileContents.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).flatMap { return Int($0) }`. I separated it to demonstrate the steps involved.

Answer (score 5):

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

### Solution

```
import Foundation

extension String {
    func onlyNumbers() -> [NSNumber] {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        let charset = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: " ,")
        return matches(for: "[+-]?([0-9]+([., ][0-9]*)*|[.][0-9]+)").compactMap { string in
            return formatter.number(from: string.trimmingCharacters(in: charset))
        }
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900097/4488252
    func matches(for regex: String) -> [String] {
        guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [.caseInsensitive]) else { return [] }
        let matches  = regex.matches(in: self, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, self.count))
        return matches.compactMap { match in
            guard let range = Range(match.range, in: self) else { return nil }
            return String(self[range])
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
let text = "dasdxcw 12345678 eadwd 333.222 reqw 3 333 444.22, sfsa 44. qewqwdsaw qe aw, 0.123456678 and .23 asdasdas 32,322,222,444.8"
print("Original text: \(text)")
print("Only numbers: \(text.onlyNumbers())")
```

### Results

```
//Original text: dasdxcw 12345678 eadwd 333.222 reqw 3 333 444.22, sfsa 44. qewqwdsaw qe aw, 0.123456678 and .23 asdasdas 32,322,222,444.8
//Only numbers: [12345678, 333.222, 3333444.22, 44, 0.123456678, 0.23, 32322222444.8]
```