# How to Check if String begins with Alphabet Letter in Swift 5?

Tags: ios, swift, string, alphabetical

**Problem:** i am currently trying to `Sort a List in SwiftUI` according to the `Items First Character`. I also would like to implement a `Section` for all Items, which `doesn't begin` with a `Character of the Alphabet` *(Numbers, Special Chars)*.

**My Code so far:**

```swift
let nonAlphabetItems = items.filter { $0.name.uppercased() != /* beginns with A - Z */ }
```

**Does anyone has a Solution for this Issue. Of course I could do a huge Loop Construct, however I hope there is a more elegant way.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does letter includes non standard letters or only "A"..."Z"? Does "Ç" should be considered a letter?

Comment: @LeoDabus Only Standard Letters "A" to "Z". Special Letters like "Ç" as well as Numbers and Special Chars should pass Filtering.

Comment: @LeoDabus "Ç" is a standard letter: it's in Unicode standard, and the standard recognizes it as a letter.  There are also lots of standard letters in the Greek or the Cyrillic alphabet.  I suppose that with "non-standard" you mean "[non roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet)"  ?   ;-)

Comment: @Christophe that’s why I asked. Ç is a letter but it is not in the English alphabet

Comment: @LeoDabus Sorry, no offense. I even upvoted your interesting answer.  I tease you on the terminology.  "Standard alphabet" is not "English alphabet" except for 379 millions of [English-native speakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers) among 7,9 billions of [people in the world](https://www.live-counter.com/world-population/). So 96% of the world population have another understanding of "standard alphabet" ;-)   By the way,  English alphabet is not even English, it is roman/latin ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need an occasional filter, you could simply write a condition combining standard predicates [`isLetter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127011-isletter) and [`isASCII`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127007-isascii) which are already defined for `Character`.  It's as simple as:

```
let items = [ "Abc", "01bc", "Ça va", "", "  ", ""]
let nonAlphabetItems = items.filter { $0.isEmpty || !$0.first!.isASCII || !$0.first!.isLetter }
print (nonAlphabetItems)  // -> Output:  ["01bc", "Ça va", "", "  ", ""]
```

If the string is not empty, it has for sure a first character `$0.first!`. It is tempting to use `isLetter` , but it appears to be true for many characters in many local alphabets, including for example the antique [Egyptian hieroglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_Hieroglyphs_(Unicode_block)) like `""` or the French alphabet  with `"Ç"`and accented characters.  This is why you need to restrict it to ASCII letters, to limit yourself to the [roman alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_alphabet).

Comment: No need to force unwrap `$0.isEmpty || $0.first?.isASCII == false || $0.first?.isLetter == false`

Answer (score 3):

You can check if a string range `"A"..."Z"` contains the first letter of your name property:

```
struct Item {
    let name: String
}
```

---

```
let items: [Item] = [.init(name: "Def"),.init(name: "Ghi"),.init(name: "123"),.init(name: "Abc")]

let nonAlphabetItems = items.filter { !("A"..."Z" ~= ($0.name.first?.uppercased() ?? "#")) }

nonAlphabetItems  // [{name "123"}]
```

---

Expanding on this topic we can extend `Character` to add a `isAsciiLetter` property:

```
extension Character {
    var isAsciiLetter: Bool { "A"..."Z" ~= self || "a"..."z" ~= self }
}
```

This would allow to extend `StringProtocol` to check is a string starts with an ascii letter:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var startsWithAsciiLetter: Bool { first?.isAsciiLetter == true }
}
```

And just a helper to negate a boolean property:

```
extension Bool {
    var negated: Bool { !self }
}
```

---

Now we can filter the items collection as follow:

```
let nonAlphabetItems = items.filter(\.name.startsWithAsciiLetter.negated)   // [{name "123"}]
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. What exactly is the ~= Operator?

Comment: In this case it is the same as contains. It is called pattern matching operator. This can also be written as `{!("A"..."Z").contains(($0.name.first?.uppercased() ?? "#")) }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSCharacterSet in the following way :

````
let phrase = "Test case"
let range = phrase.rangeOfCharacter(from: characterSet)

// range will be nil if no letters is found
if let test = range {
    println("letters found")
}
else {
   println("letters not found")
}```
````

Comment: OP is trying to check the first character only "beginns with"

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with ascii value

```
extension String {
    var fisrtCharacterIsAlphabet: Bool {
         guard let firstChar = self.first else { return false }
         let unicode = String(firstChar).unicodeScalars
         let ascii = Int(unicode[unicode.startIndex].value)
         return (ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90) || (ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122)
    }
    
}

var isAlphabet = "Hello".fisrtCharacterIsAlphabet
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Character` type has a property for this:

```
let x: Character = "x"
x.isLetter // true for letters, false for punctuation, numbers, whitespace, ...
```

Note that this will include characters from other alphabets (Greek, Cyrillic, Chinese, ...).

As `String` is a `Sequence` with `Element` equal to `Character`, we can use the `.first` property to get the first char.

With this, you can filter your items:

```
let filtered = items.filter { $0.name.first?.isLetter ?? false }
```

Comment: `isLetter` will include undesired letters as well. That's why I've posted a comment asking it at first place. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127011-isletter

Answer (score 0):

You can get this done through this simple `String` extension

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var isFirstCharacterAlp: Bool {
        first?.isASCII == true && first?.isLetter == true
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
print ("H1".isFirstCharacterAlp)
print ("ابراهيم1".isFirstCharacterAlp)
```

**Output**

```
true
false
```

Happy Coding!

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24502779/5807290)

Comment: Why not simply Character property isLetter as suggested by [Palle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65361187/2303865)? Btw that won't solve the question because it will include non ascii letters as well

Comment: @LeoDabus I have updated my answer. Thanks for pointing out the ASCII constraint I overlooked the comments

Comment: IMO `self.first?.isASCII == true` reads much better than `self.first?.isASCII ?? false`. Btw parentheses is not needed `first?.isASCII == true && first?.isLetter == true`

Comment: @LeoDabus Yeah removing the paranthesis looks cleaner, agreed and updated the code block

Comment: I would just remove the `self` prefix and extend `StringProtocol` instead to support substrings as well

Comment: Agreed Thanks for the suggestions.